# Android - Show full screen notification when app is in background

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

I'd like to show a **full screen** notification when my app is receiving an incoming call.
Basically the same as WhatsApp, ie. when the phone received a notification and the app is not started, I want to show a view (activity, notification, whatever you want to call it) that is taking the full size of the screen.
Everything is working except one thing: the "view" is never shown in full screen, only as a classic notification.

Here's my code, pretty straightforward.
Can someone pinpoint any issue in it? Am I missing some kind of permission or something?
Any help would be welcomed.

```
Intent incomingCallDialog = new Intent(context, IncomingCallActivity.class);
        incomingCallDialog.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        incomingCallDialog.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        if (context.getApplication() != null && ((MyApplication) context.getApplication()).getCurrentActivity() == null) {
            PendingIntent fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    incomingCallDialog, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.incoming_call_from, email));
            notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
            notificationBuilder.setContentText(caller.getName());
            notificationBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);
            notificationBuilder.setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL);
            notificationBuilder.setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true);
            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent);
            notificationBuilder.setTimeoutAfter(30 * 1000);
            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            notificationBuilder.setWhen(0);

            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            String channelId = "my_channel";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    channelId,
                    "channelname",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            notificationBuilder.setChannelId(channelId);

            manager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_CALL_ID);
            manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_CALL_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
        } else {
            context.startActivity(incomingCallDialog);
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by **full screen** notification? can you share an instance where you have seen a full screen notification?

Comment: WhatsApp incoming call is a good example. A notification that will show a full screen activity instead of just a "badge" on top of the screen

Comment: So now you talk about a full screen activity. Where is the full screen notification? Or what should it be?

Comment: I edited my question for clarity. Notification/activity is semantic here, call it however you want, as long as it takes the full size of the screen on the phone, and not just a small popup appearing on top of the screen.